# Did our prophet[pbuh] order the sahabah to murder sleeping people?

Tags: prophets, jihad

Did our prophet[pbuh] order the sahabah to murder sleeping people according to [Sahih al-Bukhari 3022](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3022) ?

The true prophet did something like this? Or what's the context behind it? Please answer with detailed reference. The thing is causing a lot of trouble in my head.

Comment: Abu Rafi’ was a known enemy of the Prophet. He used to make deals with the prophets enemies, so he is clearly at war with muslims. does it really matter if he’s sleeping or not .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from Sahih Bukhari so it is obvious that it is considered authentic.

The context behind it is that Abu Rafi was a blasphemer against the Prophet ﷺ and used to financially support the tribes who fought him, as is noted in another hadith:

> وكان أبو رافع يؤذي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ويعين عليه
>
> Abu Rafi` used to hurt Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and help his enemies against him.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4039)</sup>

Further context is that the tribes of Aws and Khazraj used to compete with each other. When Aws had dealt with [Ka`b bin Al-Ashraf](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4037) the Khazraj wanted to match them by dealing with Abu Rafi'.

It is permissible to kill a Harbi Kafir to whom dawah has reached once and he has rejected it. Further a blasphemer is worse than that. And when it is permissible to kill someone then it makes no difference whether he is awake or asleep.

Comment: Sahih Bukhari was written 250 years after the Prophet.  I don’t think its right to assume everything in it is authentic